# firebase cloud functions - https.onCall(....) can Context.Auth be used?

Tags: function, firebase, oauth, cloud

I need advice becuase I’ve never tried this combination:

1. firebase app + realtime database 
   this app will be my backend and provide some cloud functions.
2. android app which will call these cloud functions.

I want to use google auth2 authentication and “protect” the cloud functions to be called by the android app only and if atuh is valid only.

Best Regards
Ivan

For expample this is my cloud functions for ‘addTickets’ scenario:

=== index.js: ===

```
exports.addTickets = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
 // data comes from client app
 const buyingRecord = data;
 console.log(‘buyingRecord: ‘ + JSON.stringify(buyingRecord));

return tickets.updateTicketsAmmount(buyingRecord)
 .then((result)=>{
 tickets.addTicketsBuyingRecord(buyingRecord);
 result.userid = buyingRecord.userid;
 result.ticketsCount = buyingRecord.ticketsCount;
 return result;
 });
});
```

====== tickets.js =======

```
exports.updateTicketsAmmount = function(buyingRecord) {
 var userRef = db.ref(‘users/’ + buyingRecord.userid);
 var amountRef = db.ref(‘users/’ + buyingRecord.userid + ‘/ticketsAmount’);
 return amountRef.transaction((current)=>{
 return (current || 0) + buyingRecord.ticketsCount;
 })
 .then(()=>{
 console.log(“amount updated for userid [“ + buyingRecord.userid + “]”);
 return userRef.once(‘value’);
 })
 .then((snapshot)=>{
 var data = snapshot.val();
 console.log(“data for userid [“ + snapshot.key + “]:” + JSON.stringify(data));
 return data;
 });
}

exports.addTicketsBuyingRecord = function(buyingRecord) {
 var historyRef = db.ref(‘ticketsBuyingHistory’);
 var newRecordRef = historyRef.push();
 return newRecordRef.set(buyingRecord)
 .then(()=>{
 console.log(‘history record added.’); 
 return newRecordRef.once(‘value’);
 })
 .then((snapshot)=>{
 var data = snapshot.val();
 console.log(‘data:’ + JSON.stringify(data));
 return data;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want only authenticated users to invoke your callable function, then simply check that `context.auth.uid` exists.  If the user is not authenticated, there will be no uid.

Comment: Hmm, yeas, I thought similar, but I'm not sure yet exactly what are the steps.  
1. android - oauth2 - authorize and get uid
2. android call cloud function sending auth info
3. cloud function get auth (maybe decode somehow) and get uid.
but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "steps".  The documentation discusses how to coordinate the client and server.  That should be all you need to know to get started.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Could you give me a hint please.
What if the updateTicketsAmmount() succeeds but addTicketBuyingRecord() fails?

The Result of the callable addTickets() will be a rejected promise, but what about the data in the db. I think they would be inconsistent - updated amount but no record about it. 

What could I do about it if I need to be 100% consistent ?
On addBuyingRecord() failure to 'fix' the amount ?
Or some transaction but I've read that in nosql db it is not the best idea to use a transaction on a such low level in the data structure.